# C# async/await. call and forget, no waiting. And long running process

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to take advantage of new (relatively) C# async/await Task based feature. I went through several examples and I got the general idea of advantages.
Here are two topics I would be very grateful if someone shares with me/us some clues or piece of code on:

1. I use to write some logging/tracking info during the "process" dozens of times (like write to a TXT file log or dump some statuses into db, etc.) I feel like it will be very efficient to do those calls asynchronously (call and forget, no waiting). But what I learned is that each async task HAS to have an await, to be truly asynchronous.
   So, what is the solution to calling the same method (with different parameter value, like message...) several times during the "main method/function" and do not wait for each call as "await"?
2. I have a pretty complicated [processA()] (class.method) which is called within a loop in the "main" class in windows service to process a "next doc" (thousands of times) (long running process). I would like to put this [processA()] in a Task and use 4-8 tasks in parallel to call the [processA()].

Any clues, useful links, or code sample will be truly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "HAS to have an await, to be truly asynchronous" - this is a misconception. A method can be asynchronous regardless of whether you await it or not. it's the method code itself that dictates the async nature. Not awaiting the method prohibits you from catching exceptions so if the call fails it could bring the whole app down with it (Save for web apps).

Comment: ``Enumerable.Range(0, threadCount).Select(tId => Task.Start(() => processA())``. Task.Start is generally frowned upon but it can work to forcibly make synchronous methods async-compatible. It's a fake asynchrony so watch out.

Comment: This is defenently possible. I think you need to remember that even though a task needs to be awaited, it doesnt have to be awaited initially. You can create all tasks with Task.Run or Task.Factory.StartNew which will kick them off. Then you can WaitAll them. You probably also want to look into Parallel.For loop.

Comment: @Machinarius To your point, I think it's important to note that the TaskScheduler is responsible for where the work is run and Task.Start simply uses the CurrentSynconizationContext. This can be achieved even when using Task.Factory.StartNew.

Answer (score 4):

> I feel like it will be very efficient to do those calls asynchronously (call and forget, no waiting).

The problem with fire and forget is that you have no idea whether the operation failed. This is not acceptable for most code.

Many logging frameworks synchronously write to an in-memory store which is then periodically flushed to disk/db. This gives a good tradeoff between speed and log reliability.

> I would like to put this [processA()] in a Task and use 4-8 tasks in parallel to call the [processA()].

Sounds like you're confusing asynchrony with parallel processing. If you want to use parallel processing, then use `Parallel.ForEach` or something like that; if you want to use asynchrony, then the first step is to make `processA` asynchronous, and then use `await Task.WhenAll` for all the tasks to complete.

Comment: and also on the first point - correct me if I am wrong - async can't really be truly fire and forget because it's like a boomerang - eventually it comes back to you - the (or at least, some) thread will be interrupted when the async work completes. In the case of true F&F you have to queue and handle out of process.

Comment: `async void` is always fire and forget.  `async Task` that is not awaited is also fire and forget.

Comment: @MatthewWhited: `async void` has some interesting exception handling semantics - I like to call it "fire and crash". `async Task` with a discarded task is truly fire-and-forget.

Comment: @StephenByrne: The `async` method will continue after `await` regardless of whether its returned task is discarded. But I'd still consider that "fire and forget".

Comment: @StephenCleary - ah ok, I got it, makes sense to consider it forgettable :)

Comment: Async void works... But I highly recommend you don't allow exceptions to be unhandled... Since you don't even get an unhandled exception event before the process nukes its self :)

Comment: `async void` will raise the exception on the `SynchronizationContext` that was active at the beginning of the method - this will raise app-level unhandled exception events. `async Task` just sticks the exception on the task, so if the task is discarded, the exception is (almost) silently swallowed.